# Install Ubuntu Desktop on Software RAID 1 (mirror) with encryption

Tags: encryption, raid, mdadm

I used to use Ubuntu 12.04 Alternate installer to setup my old RAID1 + encryption system. With the new LTS 14.04 (beta 2) I found the alternate installer missing which complicates installation on a RAID1 a lot. Textbased installation doesn't work because it fails to autmatically setup Wifi.

My question is: How do you install Ubuntu Desktop on a software RAID 1 with encryption?

Here's what I tried:

**Idea 1. Install on first hard disk and create RAID afterwards**

Didn't work because "Disks" warns about erasing everything.

**Idea 2. Use netboot installer**

While in principal this would work (tested in a virtualmachine) I can't get my wireless interface to work. (A work around would be to setup a plain wired interface but right now I'd like to avoid setting something like this up.)

**Idea 3. Use server installer**

I also tested this in a virtualmachine but apparently there is no Desktop package available in the installer (which is available in netboot installer). I assume this can be installed afterwards from console but my fear is that I won't get the original Ubuntu Desktop experience. What are the differences between Desktop and Server+Desktop package? ([Thread about server installation](https://askubuntu.com/a/305026/11611))

**Idea 4. Create a RAID1 from unformatted disks and install on the RAID1**

Installation works except for the last step which shows the error
"can't install grub on /dev/md127p1". I also tried to install it on any other partition without success.

I also followed the tutorial mentioned in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/294777/11611) but got stuck when I had to add the encryption partition.

1. Format the /dev/md0 as crypto
2. Wait for /dev/mapper/crypto1 to appear
3. Format crypto1 with partition table
4. Create ext4 partition

Btw: There is no option to create LVMs that the simple install option provides o_O

**Idea 5: Use "Try Ubuntu" and run text installer**

Does anyone know how to start the text installer from within the graphical live system?

Comment: If the server installer works, use that option. Post-install, reboot and install the generic kernel and ubuntu-desktop. Then re-boot to the generic kernel and remove the server kernel.

Comment: Thanks. Although I haven't tried this I think it also requires to setup Wifi in text based installer.

Comment: setting up wifi in a text based installer is not so different then a graphical one. You enter the password with the keyboard ;)

Comment: Except the autoconfigurator doesn't work or provide any selection of available wifi networks.

Comment: Not sure what autoconfigurator you are talking about. See http://blog.tplus1.com/blog/2008/06/13/how-to-connect-to-a-wireless-network-from-the-ubuntu-command-line/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out a solution. The trick here is to use the textbased installer in a Virtualbox to circumvent setting up wifi. The installation takes a lot of time (+2h) but it's intended to be easy.

**Use Virtualbox as a DHCP server and install to rawdisks via the textbased installer**

1. Boot from live Desktop, choose "Try Ubuntu", setup your wifi and download Minimal iso (server should work too and maybe speed up the installation.)
2. In Software Center select VirtualBox -> more info -> add multiverse as source -> install
3. Create raw disks via:

   `sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename sda.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda
   sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename sdb.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdb`
4. start Virtualbox as root `sudo virtualbox`, add the newly created raw disks and the netboot iso
5. Boot and choose expert install, go through the first install steps...
6. Add `parted` as installer package
7. Create the partitions (note that Virtualbox may choose different names for devices!)

   1. sda1: 0.5GB, ext2, use as software RAID
   2. sda2: remaining space, use as software RAID
   3. sdb1: 0.5GB, ext2, use as software RAID
   4. sdb2: remaining space, use as software RAID
   5. create software RAID -> installer should offer an option to write to disk
   6. md0: use as ext2 /boot
   7. md1: use as "LVM"
   8. add a LVM group and add a logical partition
   9. lvm: use as "encrypted"
   10. add encrypted partition -> finish -> installer should ask for passphrase
8. add user! (I forgot this at the first attempt, OMG)
9. the following only applies to Minimal iso I think: install base system, in `tasksel` add  "ubuntu-desktop" and as kernel select "linux-generic-lts-trusty"
10. add the bootloader to /dev/sda
11. finish it

As of 2014-04-19 I got an error during bootup `Error: diskfilter writes are not supported.
Press any key to continue...`
See [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1274320/comments/28) for a solution.